# how to show markup on a chessboard square in chessboard.js

Tags: javascript, css, api, chessboard.js

I'm building a visualization for the [Knight's tour problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour).

I'm using [chessboard-element](https://justinfagnani.github.io/chessboard-element/) (Which is basically a modern version of the [chessboard.js library](https://chessboardjs.com/)), and it has been smooth until I've reached this barrier.

**My issue is:** I need a way to show markup that indicates the number of the last-played move.
[Image of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnqiA.png)

As you can see in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnqiA.png) above, when the knight is moved manually by the user, or if the move is indicated by the [Warnsdorff's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Warnsdorff%27s_rule), I need the resulted square to be marked up with the number of the move [Image describing seemingly the desired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0L27.jpg).

My current approach to this problem is by accessing the element in the DOM using its id and attaching the desired markup for it, but the issue is: even if I tried to do so, it will result in the knight not showing for some reason [A picture showing the weird behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpixW.png).

```js
const targetId = "square-" + target
const targetEl = Array.from(this.board.shadowRoot.querySelector("[part~='board']").children).find(({ id }) => id === targetId)

targetEl.innerHTML += `<h4>${this.takenSpots.length}</h4>`
```

Is there's an API in the chessboard-element library that I can use to accomplish the desired output?
If not, is there a css-hack (or similar) around this problem?
If not, is there any other similar chessboard libraries that I can use to solve this issue?
If not, how do you suggest to approach this problem?

Comment: Hi Obada, welcome at SO! You will need to post a [reprex] (preferably running) of what you created. From you pictures we can only guess what you did with the code.

Comment: Thanks Rene. My code won't really help anyone with solving this issue, I'm basically asking is there's a way to add markup to the squares in the [chessboard.-element](https://justinfagnani.github.io/chessboard-element/) library?